# How can I handle a shortcut key in every WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I want to open the help file to a page based on some custom logic. How can I handle the user pressing F1 on all of my windows (main window and modal dialogs) ?

I know how to handle F1 in a single window, but can this be done globally, so I don't have to add the same code to all of my windows ?

Below is the test with which I've tried out that F1 does not work on the child window.

Window1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Help"
                        Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open a new window"
                Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Help");
        }

        void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            new Window().ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the answer on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2007/07/26/a-context-sensitive-help-provider-in-wpf.aspx) page.
That is, put this in the main window's constructor for example:

```
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window),
    new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Help,
        (x, y) => MessageBox.Show("Help")));
```

Comment: It works for child controls either. I.e. if child control is selected then it will handle F1 if handler of it's type registered, otherwise window handler is triggered.